# "One bee sting and game over" meaning in context

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across the following:

> **A**: I'm actually scared to ride horses.
> **B**: You are?
> **A**: Yeah.
> **B**: Why?
> **A**: *One bee sting and game over.* Right?
> **B**: No, it's not that bad.
> **A**: You have to know what you're doing, and I don't.

Am I correct in thinking that person A means that he's scared of horses because he has fallen off a horse once and that he mentions getting stung by a bee as an indirect way of saying that?
(as in: many people become scared of bees after they get stung by one.)

Comment: It is not clear from the dialogue whether your interpretation is correct, or whether A is speaking literally. Giving us the source of the quote might be helpful.

Comment: My guess would be that A once had a bad experience due to his _horse_ being stung by a bee (and probably throwing him). Is there more context available?

Comment: I've added the last part of the dialogue.

Comment: @KateBunting This makes sense. I think that's what he meant.